# Offline Firebase stub

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, firebase

I've written a front-end application in Angular which communicates with a back-end application in NodeJS. The backend application talks to a Firebase instance to fetch/store/modify data. In some occasions, I need to run this backend offline (without a connection to the Internet), so I can't connect to Firebase.

Is there any (simple) way to create a stub (e.g. using the export JSON file from Firebase) that reads from and writes to this file, to emulate a Firebase instance? I've been looking on the Internet, and some people recommended MongoDB, but this would require quite a lot of modification to my code.

Comment: I'm quite interested - in what occasion you need to run your server offline? Besides that Firebase will synchronise once back online.

Comment: Actually, it's a prototype application. We need to showcase it on a couple of conferences, and Internet access is often very limited there. To play safe, we consider an offline solution as a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. You can run a local firebase with [firebase-server](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server). It's worth noting it has some limitations (no Firebase auth, for instance) but that should be easier to stub.

You can read more on the firebase blog: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-04-24-end-to-end-testing-firebase-server.html